# How to know which regular expression pattern is matched in SQL Query

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I am writing a SQL query and I have **n** regular expressions to match in the query.

```
SELECT * FROM
Sample_Table
WHERE
(REGEXP_CONTAINS(content, r"[a-z0-9A-Z]{40}") OR -- expression 1
REGEXP_CONTAINS(content, r"[0-9a-z]{32}") OR -- expression 2
..................
REGEXP_CONTAINS(content, r"[a-z0-9]{80}") OR -- expression n-1
REGEXP_CONTAINS(content, r"[a-z0-9A-Z\%]{35}")) -- expression n
```

Now, when I get back the result, I want to know the particular returned row is matched by expression 1 or expression 2. One option would have been to run each regular expression once and tag the result. But, I have to run all the regular expression in one query because of resource limitation in Google BigQuery.

Is there any way to tag each returned result row with the matched regular expression?

Comment: what if it matches both 1 and 2?

Comment: Any one of the regular expression will do but would like to capture both 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
with patterns as (
  select 1 pattern_id, r"[a-z0-9A-Z]{40}" pattern union all
  select 2, r"[0-9a-z]{32}" union all
  select 3, r"[a-z0-9]{80}" union all
  select 4, r"[a-z0-9A-Z\%]{35}"
)
select any_value(t).*, string_agg('' || pattern_id) matches  
from Sample_Table t, patterns p
where regexp_contains(content, pattern)
group by format('%t', t)
```

if you have better column to use for `group by` you should use it  - for example

```
select any_value(t.sample_repo_name), string_agg('' || pattern_id) as matches  
from `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.sample_contents` t, patterns p
where regexp_contains(content, pattern)
group by id
```

Comment: I am getting "Output string too long while evaluating FORMAT; limit 1048576" in the Bigquery console. Here is my tried sql query https://pastebin.com/fUZec9V9. Can you please check?

Comment: see update. i used very generic approach because you have not provided any info about your data.

Comment: I have 100 regular expressions to be matched as patterns. When I ran with those, I got error "Operation timed out after 6.0 hours. Consider reducing the amount of work performed by your operation so that it can complete within this limit". This is my code https://pastebin.com/2MFtNJrD. Can you please check if there is any other way to avoid the error and get the same desired result of a repository name matched with different regular expressions.