# How to efficiently match regular expressions in a large dataset of Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I have almost 750 regular expressions to match against the [Google BigQuery GitHub Public Dataset](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/public-datasets/github-on-bigquery-analyze-all-the-open-source-code). At first, I was writing the query as below:

```
SELECT * FROM
Sample_Table
WHERE
(REGEXP_CONTAINS(content, r"[a-z0-9A-Z]{40}") OR -- expression 1
REGEXP_CONTAINS(content, r"[0-9a-z]{32}") OR -- expression 2
..................
REGEXP_CONTAINS(content, r"[a-z0-9]{80}") OR -- expression n-1
REGEXP_CONTAINS(content, r"[a-z0-9A-Z\%]{35}")) -- expression n
```

But, in this case, I did not know which regular expression has been matched for a returned result row. Then, after this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73102359/4299527), I changed my query to below:

```
with patterns as (
 SELECT 1 pattern_id, r"(?i)(?:abbysale)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-z0-9A-Z]{40})\b" pattern
UNION ALL SELECT 2, r"(?i)(?:abstract)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([0-9a-z]{32})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 3, r"(?i)(?:abuseipdb)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-z0-9]{80})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 4, r"(?i)(?:accuweather)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}([a-z0-9A-Z\%]{35})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 5, r"\b(aio\_[a-zA-Z0-9]{28})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 6, r"(?i)(?:adobe)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-z0-9]{32})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 7, r"(?i)(?:adzuna)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-z0-9]{32})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 8, r"(?i)(?:aeroworkflow)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-zA-Z0-9^!]{20})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 9, r"(?i)(?:agora)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-z0-9]{32})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 10, r"(?i)(?:aha)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([0-9a-f]{64})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 11, r"(?i)(?:airbrake)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-zA-Z-0-9]{32})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 12, r"(?i)(?:airship)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([0-9Aa-zA-Z]{91})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 13, r"\b(key[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{14})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 14, r"(?i)(?:airvisual)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-z0-9-]{36})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 15, r"(?i)(?:alconost)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([0-9Aa-z]{32})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 16, r"(?i)(?:alegra)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-z0-9-]{20})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 17, r"(?i)(?:aletheiaapi)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([A-Z0-9]{32})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 18, r"(?i)(?:algolia)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-zA-Z0-9]{32})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 19, r"\b([a-zA-Z0-9]{30})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 20, r"(?i)(?:alienvault)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-z0-9]{64})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 21, r"(?i)(?:allsports)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-z0-9]{64})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 22, r"(?i)(?:amadeus)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([0-9A-Za-z]{32})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 23, r"(?i)(?:ambee)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([0-9a-f]{64})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 24, r"(?i)(?:amplitude)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([0-9a-f]{32})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 25, r"\b([0-9a-z]{8}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{12})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 26, r"(?i)(?:apacta)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-z0-9-]{36})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 27, r"(?i)(?:api2cart)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([0-9a-f]{32})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 28, r"\b(sk_live_[a-z0-9A-Z-]{93})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 29, r"(?i)(?:apideck)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-z0-9A-Z]{40})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 30, r"(?i)(?:apiflash)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-z0-9]{32})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 31, r"(?i)(?:apiflash)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-zA-Z0-9\S]{21,30})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 32, r"(?i)(?:apifonica)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([0-9a-z]{11}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{12})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 33, r"\b(apify\_api\_[a-zA-Z-0-9]{36})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 34, r"(?i)(?:apimatic)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}@[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,12}.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,5})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 35, r"(?i)(?:apimatic)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-z0-9-\S]{8,32})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 36, r"(?i)(?:apiscience)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-bA-Z0-9\S]{22})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 37, r"(?i)(?:apitemplate)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([0-9a-zA-Z]{39})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 38, r"(?i)(?:apollo)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-zA-Z0-9]{22})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 39, r"(?i)(?:appcues)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-z0-9-]{36})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 40, r"(?i)(?:appcues)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-z0-9-]{39})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 41, r"(?i)(?:appcues)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([0-9]{5})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 42, r"(?i)(?:appfollow)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([0-9A-Za-z]{20})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 43, r"(?i)(?:appsynergy)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-z0-9]{64})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 44, r"(?i)(?:apptivo)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-z0-9-]{36})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 45, r"\b([a-zA-Z0-9]{73})"
UNION ALL SELECT 46, r"\b([A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9\-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])\.jfrog\.io)"
UNION ALL SELECT 47, r"(?i)(?:artsy)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([0-9a-zA-Z]{32})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 48, r"(?i)(?:asana)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([a-z\/:0-9]{51})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 49, r"(?i)(?:asana)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([0-9]{1,}\/[0-9]{16,}:[A-Za-z0-9]{32,})\b"
UNION ALL SELECT 50, r"(?i)(?:assemblyai)(?:.|[\n\r]){0,40}\b([0-9a-z]{32})\b"
)

SELECT any_value(F.repo_name) AS repo_name, string_agg(DISTINCT ('' ||  pattern_id)) as matches  
FROM bigquery-public-data.github_repos.contents AS C
INNER JOIN bigquery-public-data.github_repos.files AS F
ON C.id = F.id
,patterns p
WHERE NOT BINARY AND regexp_contains(C.content, p.pattern)
GROUP BY F.repo_name
```

Here, my goal is to have the repository name with the distinct matched regular expressions in a comma separated string like below:

[image]

Though I want to run all my regular expressions because of the Google BigQuery resource limitation, but I ran the above query with only 50 regular expressions. Unfortunately, I got timeout error.

Operation timed out after 6.0 hours. Consider reducing the amount of work performed by your operation so that it can complete within this limit.

[image]

I am not sure how can I optimize the query. Can anyone please help?

Comment: `(?:.|[\n\r])` is a performance killer. Always just use `.`  and prepend the patterns with `(?s)` to allow it to match across lines.

Comment: Are you suggesting like this (?i)(?:abbysale)(?s.){0,40}\b([a-z0-9A-Z]{40})\b ??

Comment: No, `(?s.){0,40}` => `(?s).{0,40}`. Or, to apply to your regex, `(?is)abbysale.{0,40}\b([a-z0-9A-Z]{40})\b`

Comment: Suppose, I want to match the string "d558677a79ad45ccaf2204170bf00e16" when the word `assemblyai` is around 20 characters of the capturing group that follows. When I tried like this https://pasteboard.co/JFdDTPPuTwY6.png, it did not work. How can I match such occurrences when the specific word is present within 20 characters of the capturing group \b([a-z0-9A-Z]{32})\b ??

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Can you please check my above comment?

Comment: Your pattern looks fine (note you have specified a 0 to 40 chars window), can you share the regex101 link here?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, here is the link https://regex101.com/r/cKo53B/1 . Yeah, I tried with 40 characters later on.

Comment: `(?is)assemblyai.{0,43}\b([0-9a-z]{32})\b` works

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Can you please explain why (?:.|[\n\r]) is a performance killer? just want to learn the reason.

Comment: There are 43 chars between `assembly.ai` and the 32-char whole word, that is why you [did not have a match](https://regex101.com/r/cKo53B/1). Yes, `(?:.|[\n\r])*?` is a performance killer. If you see a solution with this construct, do not trust them.

Answer (score 1):

The `(?:.|[\n\r])*?` is a performance killer regex construct.

The only regex flavor that requires this form of matching any char is ElasticSearch, in all others, there are much more efficient ways.

Here, you can use something like

```
(?is)assemblyai.{0,43}\b([0-9a-z]{32})\b
```

Make sure your limiting (range/interval) quantifier can match long enough to get to the 32-char whole word (hence, I changed 40 to 43).